# Include php scripts in Google Charts API

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I am trying to simulate a database (with a php) for a Google Chart. I have trouble to interface the php to the Google Charts. So far, I have tried to use JSON.stringify(), JSON.parse(),... Unfortunatly, I didn't find a proper way to include the generated data. What am i doing wrong?

I have written the following test.php in order to automatically generate data:

```
$fakedate = new DateTime('2014-01-01 14:05:00');
$testTime = $fakedate->format('[H,i,s]');
$testNb = rand ( 1000 , 5000 );

for ($i = 0; $i <= 47; $i++) 
{
    $chartsdata[$i] = array($testTime, $testNb);

    $fakedate->add(new DateInterval('PT10M'));
    $testTime = $fakedate->format('[H,i,s]');
    $testNb = rand ( 1000 , 5000 );
}       
echo json_encode($chartsdata);
```

On the other hand, I have written the following column charts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() 
    {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('timeofday','testTime');
        data.addColumn('number','testNb');

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var obj = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
        data.addRows(obj);

        var options = {
            title:  'Chart title',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This section of code doesn't seem right:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
```

You need to set up a success handler, not assign jsonData to $.ajax.responseText (I don't think there is such a property there)

It'd be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
             jsonData = data; 
        }
    });
```

Since the call is synchronous then $.ajax would be blocking so no the success handler should be called before creating the chart.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this in javascript.  The first, using your code as a basis, requires you to use `JSON.parse`:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('timeofday','testTime');
    data.addColumn('number','testNb');

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    data.addRows(obj);

    var options = {
        title:  'Chart title',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The second, alluded to in hrgui's answer, is to use a `success` handler in the AJAX call:

```
function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('timeofday','testTime');
            data.addColumn('number','testNb');
            data.addRows(jsonData);

            var options = {
                title:  'Chart title',
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
}
```

The second method is generally preferred, but both will work.